# Refresh a list content with another list in Python

Tags: python, list, extend

How would I extend the content of a given list with another given list without using the method `.extend()`? I imagine that I could use something with dictionaries.

**Code**

```
>>> tags  =['N','O','S','Cl']
>>> itags =[1,2,4,3]

>>> anew =['N','H']
>>> inew =[2,5]
```

I need a function which returns the refreshed lists

```
tags  =['N','O','S','Cl','H'] 
itags =[3,2,4,3,5]
```

When an element is already in the list, the number in the other list is added. If I use the `extend()` method, the the element `N` will appear in list `tags` twice:

```
>>> tags.extend(anew)
>>>itags.extend(inew)
>>> print tags,itags
     ['N','O','S','Cl','N','H'] [1,2,4,3,5,2,5]
```

Comment: Can we presume elements in `tags` are unique? Does order matter (apart from matching `tags` to `itags`)?

Comment: why does itags have two 3's and no 1?

Comment: I don’t get how you got to the new `itags`. Where did the `1` go, why is there a `3` at the beginning?

Comment: either way, i'm betting you want `set`

Comment: He wants `dict` actually. Why are there two separate lists?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#collections.Counter) for this.

```
from collections import Counter
tags = Counter({"N":1, "O":2, "S": 4, "Cl":3})
new = Counter({"N": 2, "H": 5})

tags = tags + new
print tags
```

output:

```
Counter({'H': 5, 'S': 4, 'Cl': 3, 'N': 3, 'O': 2})
```

Comment: To generate the dict that `Counter` wants, the OP could use `dict(zip(tags, itags))`.

Comment: Thank you all! I didn't know this library 'collections'. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

If the order of elements matters, I'd use `collections.Counter` like so:

```
from collections import Counter

tags  = ['N','O','S','Cl']
itags = [1,2,4,3]

new  = ['N','H']
inew = [2,5]

cnt = Counter(dict(zip(tags, itags))) + Counter(dict(zip(new, inew)))
out = tags + [el for el in new if el not in tags]
iout = [cnt[el] for el in out]

print(out)
print(iout)
```

If the order does not matter, there is a simpler way to obtain `out` and `iout`:

```
out = cnt.keys()
iout = cnt.values()
```

If you don't *have* to use a pair of lists, then working with `Counter` directly is a natural fit for your problem.

Comment: If order matters, this is the way to do it, if it doesn't, then the better option is to just leave it as a `Counter()` and have a more appropriate data structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to maintain the order, you may want to use an OrderedDict instead of a Counter:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

tags = ['N','O','S','Cl']
itags = [1,2,4,3]

new = ['N','H']
inew = [2,5]

od = OrderedDict(zip(tags, itags))
for x, i in zip(new, inew):
    od[x] = od.setdefault(x, 0) + i

print od.keys()
print od.values()
```

On Python 3.x, use `list(od.keys())` and `list(od.values())`.

Comment: Using a `Counter` then introducing the order back as in NPE's answer also maintains order.

Comment: True, but I think it is more straightforward to handle the counting manually than the ordering.  It is also more efficient if this is being done repeatedly.